# Use the remote debugging protocol in the Chromium based Opera

Tags: opera

I use the Google Chrome remote debugging protocol to get benchmarking information of the page loading process with Google Chrome. I would like to switch to Opera which should offer the same functionality now that it runs on Chromium.

I started Opera with the cli parameters "--remote-debugging-port=9222 --enable-benchmarking --enable-net-benchmarking" similar to starting Google Chrome. I discovered that benchmarking seams not to be started in Opera - the chrome.benchmarking object is not visible to JavaScript.

I didn't find any documentation on the cli parameters for Opera, neither how to work with the remote debugging protocol in Opera.

Does anybody know how benchmarking can be enabled and/or the remote debugging protocol works in Opera?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you don't need this anymore, but I did today.

For some reason (maybe it's by design, but I didn't bother to check), you can't really start two separate instances of Chropera. Therefore, you first have to exit opera (from the menu to save your session).
Then, find your installation directory, and start Opera with the params:

```
C:\PROGRA~2\OperaNew\31.0.1889.174>opera --remote-debugging-port=9222 "http://www.opera.com"
```

(Maybe you can use `launcher.exe`, but I didn't bother checking)

Then, using another browser, visit http://localhost:9222. Maybe you can use the same one, but again, I didn't bother checking.
Now it's just the same as the Chrom(e|ium) protocol.

Hope that helps somebody.

Comment: Even though he may not need it, there are many people who do. The state of Web debugging is atrocious -- between being able to debug Web pages running in Chrome, with Chrome and not being able to debug Web pages running on iOS without having a Mac, there isn't much left for an option except Weinre which hasn't been maintained for years and injects code in your page. So yes, hello everyone who needs to debug Web applications and finds out there isn't much out there that is generic and works across devices, networks and clients.